# Code worked in Overleaf but not in MiKTeX

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use [Royal Initialen](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/royalin/royalin.tex) to decorate one of my document. The code I use is,

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\usefont{T1}{fvm}{m}{n}}
\setkomafont{section}{\usefont{T1}{fvs}{b}{n}\Large}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\input RoyalIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{RoyalIn}{xl}{n}}
\begin{document}
\section*{Royal Initialen}
\subsection*{\textbackslash initfamily}
\normalfont\initfamily
\fontsize{12mm}{12mm}\selectfont THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE SLEAZY DOG
\newpage
\normalfont\initfamily
\input fonttable
\end{document}
```

But I am getting error message. I also tried to compile the code using [Overleaf](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjy24zVmerHAhUlF6YKHW0nBmw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.overleaf.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFjzfUtzV0BLyPfQRohI2BHlSLNzw) and there the same code except `\input fonttable` worked. Why is this happening and how can I get rid of the problem?

Comment: By updating your miktex!. It works here.

Comment: @HarishKumar: How can I update MiKTeX?

Comment: Follow this answer: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by the op.